# render 'new' if save fails not working correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails and am practicing by building a simple blog type app. I have my PostsController set up to render the 'posts/new' page if @post.save fails due to a field being left blank.

```
def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)

  if @post.save
    redirect_to @post
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

This is in accordance to 5.10 [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html). As a user, when I click 'Submit' so save the post with a field left blank, the html for 'new' is loaded but the URL I am sent to is '/posts' instead of 'posts/new'. Is it possible that my routes are screwed up?

Comment: no that is the correct behavior.  you are being sent to `/posts` via a `POST` request which goes to the create action.

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing is the correct behavior. When you make a post request, the URL should change to whatever URL you are posting to.

If you want the url to be the new url, then you should do a redirect instead of render in your controller. But when you do a redirect, you will lose all your validation related information.

Comment: Does this mean all the fields will be cleared? Can you direct me to a place where I can learn how to prevent the fields from being cleared? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confused about how render and redirect_to works. **A render doesn't send a fresh request to the server like a redirect_to does**

*When you submit your form you send a post request /posts to your server and hence the url changes to /posts but inside your create method you have validation errors and hence your action render new action **but render doesn't send a fresh request to the server and hence your url remains same.*** Checkout how [`render and redirect_to works`](http://blog.markusproject.org/?p=3313)