# Devise redirects to index action on error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using devise, and is having an issue if you try to signup with an existing email.

When you signup you do it from this url:

```
http://localhost:3000/accounts/new
```

So I have an account, where I add a user (devise). If I try to signup as a user which already exists I get the correct error:

> "Users email has already been taken"

But it redirects to `http://localhost:3000/accounts`

The controller looks a bit like this:

```
 def create
    name = account_params[:name]

    first_name =  Modules::NameHelpers.get_first_name(name)
    last_name = Modules::NameHelpers.get_last_name(name)

    @account = Account.new(account_params_wo_user_name)
    @account.users.first.first_name = first_name
    @account.users.first.last_name = last_name

    respond_to do |format|
        if @account.save
            sign_in @account.users.first

            format.html { redirect_to root_path, notice: "Thanks for signing up." }
            format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @account }
        else
            format.html { render action: 'new' }
            format.json { render json: @account.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end
```

I can't seem to find what redirects to the index page.

**Update**:
Here is the form:

```
<%= form_for(@account) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', :object => f.object %>

    <div>
      <%= f.label :name, 'Account Name' %> <br />
      <%= f.text_field :name, :required => true, :placeholder => 'Your account name' %>
    </div>

    <%= f.fields_for :users do |user_form| %>
        <div><%= user_form.label :name %><br />
          <%= user_form.text_field :name, :autofocus => true, :required => true, :placeholder => 'Your name' %></div>

        <div><%= user_form.label :email %><br />
          <%= user_form.email_field :email, :required => true, :placeholder => 'Your email' %></div>

        <div><%= user_form.label :password, :required => true %><br />
          <%= user_form.password_field :password, :required => true, :placeholder => 'Enter a 8 character password'%></div>

        <div><%= user_form.label :password_confirmation, :required => true %><br />
          <%= user_form.password_field :password_confirmation, :required => true, :placeholder => 'Confirm password' %></div>
    <% end %>

    <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: can you post your logs

Comment: You mention it directs to the `/accounts` path - does it still show the form? I think this is a standard Rails issue

Comment: @RichPeck you are right. I forgot the form. It has now been added.

Comment: that's not the index - it's the create URL. What exactly is happening that shouldn't be happening?

Comment: @Dofs You should change your questions title, it's a create url not index. If your form has validation error then this is the way it should be. For details checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25216738/how-is-the-new-action-redirected-to-create-in-rails/25216792#25216792

Comment: Thanks @Mandeep, can I have you add it as the answer?

Comment: @Dofs are you sure this is what you were looking for? Because i just saw that link and i think i posted wrong like. I wanted to paste this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25084345/render-new-if-save-fails-not-working-correctly/25084722#25084722